# Python inspect.getclasstree и model для QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtreeview

Пожалуйста, помогите заполнить корректно модель для отображения дерева классов в `QTreeView`.

Модель строится по результату инспекции от `inspect.getclasstree`. Я запутался в рекурсии и не понимаю где какие parent нужно передавать.

Поиски информации в интернет дают одни и те же примеры, в которых указана рекурсия с печатью в консоль. Эти варианты мне не подходят. Нужно дерево в *PyQt5*.

В ниже приведеном коде вся магия в `def populate_tree_measurements`:

```py
import sys
import inspect
import pyclbr
from pprint import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QTreeView, QMainWindow


class AAA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "AAA_title"
    def get_class_title(self):
        print(self.title)
        return self.title


class BBB_A(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        # super().__init__()
        self.title = "BBB_A_title"

    def get_class_title(self):
        return self.title

class CCC_B1(BBB_A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "CCC_B1_title"
        # print(CCC_B1.__name__)

class CCC_B2(BBB_A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "CCC_B2_title"
        # print(CCC_B2.__name__)

class DDD_A1(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_A1_title"

class DDD_DDD_A1(DDD_A1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_DDD_A1_title"

class DDD_A2(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_A2_title"

class EEE_O1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "EEE_O1_title"
        print("Класс {}".format(self.title))

class EEE_O2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "EEE_O2_title"
        print("Класс {}".format(self.title))

class MyTreeView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, tree, parent = None):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tree = tree
        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree_view)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.invisibleRootItem()
        root_node_measurements = "Измерения"
        model_measurements = QtGui.QStandardItem(root_node_measurements)
        self.populate_tree_measurements(self.tree, model_measurements, node_name=root_node_measurements)
        model.appendRow(model_measurements)

        # self.populate_tree_measurements(self.tree, model)
        # model_measurements.appendRow(model)
        # model.appendRow(model_measurements)

        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Дерево классов')
        self.tree_view.expandAll()
        # self.tree_view.collapseAll()
        # self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

    def populate_tree_measurements(self, tree, parent, node_name, indent=0, has_child=False):
        if isinstance(tree, list):
            indent += 1
            node_name_new = tree[0][0].__name__
            node = QtGui.QStandardItem(node_name_new)
            parent.appendRow(node)
            for i in range(len(tree)):
                # node_name = tree[i][0].__name__ if isinstance(tree[i], tuple) else "node_{}_{}".format(indent, i)
                # if isinstance(tree[i], tuple):
                #     if i+1 < len(tree) and isinstance(tree[i+1], list):
                #         has_child = True
                #         node_name = node_name_new = tree[i][0].__name__
                #         node.setText(node_name)
                #     else:
                #         has_child = False
                # elem_name = tree[i][0].__name__ if isinstance(tree[i], tuple) else "node_{}_{}".format(indent, i)
                self.populate_tree_measurements(
                    tree=tree[i], parent=node, node_name=node_name_new, indent=indent)
                # parent.appendRow(node)
        else:
            child_item_name = tree[0].__name__
            child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(child_item_name)
            parent.appendRow(child_item)
            print("^"*indent, "_", child_item_name, ". indent =", indent)

def main(tree):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtWidgets.qApp = app
    treeBox = MyTreeView(tree=tree)
    treeBox.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# def print_class_tree(tree, indent=1):
#     if isinstance(tree, list):
#         for node in tree:
#             print_class_tree(node, indent+1)
#     else:
#         print('  ' * indent, tree[0].__name__)
#     return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # cl = BBB()
    inspect_tree = inspect.getclasstree(
        [BBB_A, CCC_B1, AAA, DDD_A1, EEE_O1, CCC_B2, DDD_A2, DDD_DDD_A1, EEE_O2])
    print("Инспект начальный:")
    pprint(inspect_tree, indent=4)
    """ После инспекции наследования классов получаем структуру ввиде дерева классов,
    которая преобразуется в следующую структуру:
    [   (<class 'object'>, ()),
        [   (<class '__main__.AAA'>, (<class 'object'>,)),
            [   (<class '__main__.BBB_A'>, (<class '__main__.AAA'>,)),
                [   (<class '__main__.CCC_B1'>, (<class '__main__.BBB_A'>,)),
                    (<class '__main__.CCC_B2'>, (<class '__main__.BBB_A'>,))],
                (<class '__main__.DDD_A1'>, (<class '__main__.AAA'>,)),
                [(<class '__main__.DDD_DDD_A1'>, (<class '__main__.DDD_A1'>,))],
                (<class '__main__.DDD_A2'>, (<class '__main__.AAA'>,))],
            (<class '__main__.EEE_O1'>, (<class 'object'>,)),
            (<class '__main__.EEE_O2'>, (<class 'object'>,))]]
    Полученное дерево классов выводится функцией в виде:
        object
            AAA
                BBB_A
                    CCC_B1
                    CCC_B2
                DDD_A1
                    DDD_DDD_A1
                DDD_A2
            EEE_O1
            EEE_O2
    """
    # print()
    # print_class_tree(
    #     inspect_tree#, unique=True
    # )
    main(inspect_tree)
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import inspect
#import pyclbr
from pprint import pprint
#from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QTreeView, QMainWindow


class AAA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "AAA_title"
    def get_class_title(self):
        print(self.title)
        return self.title


class BBB_A(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        # super().__init__()
        self.title = "BBB_A_title"

    def get_class_title(self):
        return self.title

class CCC_B1(BBB_A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "CCC_B1_title"
        # print(CCC_B1.__name__)

class CCC_B2(BBB_A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "CCC_B2_title"
        # print(CCC_B2.__name__)

class DDD_A1(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_A1_title"

class DDD_DDD_A1(DDD_A1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_DDD_A1_title"

class DDD_A2(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_A2_title"

class EEE_O1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "EEE_O1_title"
        print("Класс {}".format(self.title))

class EEE_O2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "EEE_O2_title"
        print("Класс {}".format(self.title))


class MyTreeView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, tree, parent = None):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tree = tree
        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree_view)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        model.invisibleRootItem()
        
        root_node_measurements = "Измерения"
        self.model_measurements = QtGui.QStandardItem(root_node_measurements) 
# +++        
        self.indents = {}                                                    # +++
        
        self.populate_tree_measurements(
            self.tree, 
            self.model_measurements, 
            node_name=root_node_measurements
        )
        
        model.appendRow(self.model_measurements)
        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Дерево классов')
        self.tree_view.expandAll()

    def populate_tree_measurements(self, tree, parent, node_name, indent=0, has_child=False):
        if isinstance(tree, list):
            indent += 1
            node_name_new = tree[0][0].__name__
            node = QtGui.QStandardItem(node_name_new)
            for i in range(0, len(tree)):
                self.populate_tree_measurements(
                    tree=tree[i], parent=node, node_name=node_name_new, indent=indent)
        else:
            name_parent = tree[1][0].__name__ if len(tree[1]) else tree[0].__name__ 
            child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(name_parent)
            if not len(tree[1]): 
                parent = self.model_measurements
                parent.appendRow(child_item)                    
                if not self.indents.get(name_parent):
                    self.indents[name_parent] = child_item    
            else:
                parent = self.indents.get(name_parent)       
                child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(tree[0].__name__)
                if not self.indents.get(tree[0].__name__):
                    self.indents[tree[0].__name__] = child_item                

                parent.appendRow(child_item)
        
            child_item_name = tree[0].__name__
            print("^"*indent, "_", child_item_name, ". indent =", indent)


def main(tree):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtWidgets.qApp = app
    treeBox = MyTreeView(tree=tree)
    treeBox.resize(250, 300)
    treeBox.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inspect_tree = inspect.getclasstree(
        [BBB_A, CCC_B1, AAA, DDD_A1, EEE_O1, CCC_B2, DDD_A2, DDD_DDD_A1, EEE_O2])
    print("\nИнспект начальный:")
    pprint(inspect_tree, indent=4)
    print("")

    main(inspect_tree)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S.Nick, Спасибо за помощь! Ваше решение интересное, но не срабатывает в случае наследования от нескольких классов. Например, добавьте для проверки еще один класс:

Comment: @SssYsa   Пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @SssYsa я не проверял свое решение в случаи множественного наследования. Если вы зададите новый вопрос я попробую взглянуть на эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Вернулся снова к этой задачке. Добавил ещё класс FFF_O1 с наследованием от нескольких классов. Вот решение:

```py
import sys
import inspect
import pyclbr
from pprint import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QTreeView, QMainWindow


class AAA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "AAA_title"
    def get_class_title(self):
        return self.title


class BBB_A(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "BBB_A_title"

    def get_class_title(self):
        return self.title

class CCC_B1(BBB_A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "CCC_B1_title"

class CCC_B2(BBB_A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "CCC_B2_title"

class DDD_A1(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_A1_title"

class DDD_DDD_A1(DDD_A1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_DDD_A1_title"

class DDD_A2(AAA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "DDD_A2_title"

class EEE_O1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "EEE_O1_title"

class EEE_O2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "EEE_O2_title"

class FFF_O1(BBB_A, DDD_A1):
    def __init__(self):
        # super(DDD_A1).__init__()
        self.title = "FFF_O1_title"

class MyTreeView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, tree, parent = None):
        super(MyTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tree = tree
        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree_view)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        root_node_measurements = "Измерения"
        model_measurements = self.add_item(root_node_measurements)
        self.model.appendRow(model_measurements)
        
        self.populate_tree_measurements(self.tree, model_measurements)
        
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Дерево классов')
        self.tree_view.expandAll()
        # self.tree_view.collapseAll()
        # self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

    def add_item(self, item_name:str):
        """Возвращает QStandardItem для указанным именем"""  
        return QtGui.QStandardItem(item_name)
    
    def populate_tree_measurements(self, tree, parent:QtGui.QStandardItem):
        """
        :parameter tree: дерево элементов после инспекции.
        :parameter parent: элемент дерева. Узел пустой или c детками.
        План разбора:
            - Если tree - список, то бежим по его элементам.
                - если тип i-го элемента == tuple
                    - Если текущий элемент не последний в списке и следующий элемент типа list,
                      то следующий элемент - это узел с детишками
                        - создаем узел (i_node) с именем текущего элемента
                        - в рекурсию передаем (ветку для разбора - это элемент i+1, i_node
                        - добавляем родителю текущий узел
                    - иначе к родителю добавляем пустой узел.
        """
        if isinstance(tree, list):
            for i in range(len(tree)):
                if isinstance(tree[i], tuple):
                    elem_name = tree[i][0].__name__ # Берем имя класса
                    if i+1 < len(tree) and isinstance(tree[i+1], list):
                        # Если текущий элемент не последний в списке и следующий элемент типа list,
                        # то следующий элемент - это узел с детишками
                        i_node = QtGui.QStandardItem(elem_name)
                        self.populate_tree_measurements(tree[i+1], i_node)
                        parent.appendRow(i_node)
                    else:
                        # Обрабатываем как обычный item
                        i_elem = QtGui.QStandardItem(elem_name)
                        parent.appendRow(i_elem)


def main(tree):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtWidgets.qApp = app
    treeBox = MyTreeView(tree=tree)
    treeBox.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# def print_class_tree(tree, indent=1):
#     if isinstance(tree, list):
#         for node in tree:
#             print_class_tree(node, indent+1)
#     else:
#         print('  ' * indent, tree[0].__name__)
#     return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # cl = BBB()
    inspect_tree = inspect.getclasstree(
        [
            BBB_A, CCC_B1, AAA, DDD_A1, EEE_O1, CCC_B2, 
            DDD_A2, DDD_DDD_A1, EEE_O2, FFF_O1
        ]
    )
    print("Инспект начальный:")
    pprint(inspect_tree, indent=4)
    """ После инспекции наследования классов получаем структуру ввиде дерева классов,
    которая преобразуется в следующую структуру:
    [   (<class 'object'>, ()),
        [   (<class '__main__.AAA'>, (<class 'object'>,)),
            [   (<class '__main__.BBB_A'>, (<class '__main__.AAA'>,)),
                [   (<class '__main__.CCC_B1'>, (<class '__main__.BBB_A'>,)),
                    (<class '__main__.CCC_B2'>, (<class '__main__.BBB_A'>,))],
                (<class '__main__.DDD_A1'>, (<class '__main__.AAA'>,)),
                [(<class '__main__.DDD_DDD_A1'>, (<class '__main__.DDD_A1'>,))],
                (<class '__main__.DDD_A2'>, (<class '__main__.AAA'>,))],
            (<class '__main__.EEE_O1'>, (<class 'object'>,)),
            (<class '__main__.EEE_O2'>, (<class 'object'>,))]]
    Полученное дерево классов выводится функцией в виде:
        object
            AAA
                BBB_A
                    CCC_B1
                    CCC_B2
                DDD_A1
                    DDD_DDD_A1
                DDD_A2
            EEE_O1
            EEE_O2
    """
    # print()
    # print_class_tree(
    #     inspect_tree#, unique=True
    # )
    main(inspect_tree)
    print("")
```

[image: Консоль]

[image: Приложение]